# ref not pointing to new item after re-render reacjs

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll, intersection-observer

I am implementing the infinite scrolling in reactjs using the intersectionobserver API. Its a social-media website where i need to fetch comment for each post. Initially the showAmount is set to 15, and after each time the observer found the reference (last item), it increases the showAmount by 5 and re-render the new items. The problem with my code is, it works fine for the first time where the observer detects the item and fetch new comment and re-render. But after the re-rendering, the ref still pointing to the same item (15th item) where it should be now pointing to the latest last item (20th item).

Code:

```
// Callback function for the Intersection Observer
const handleIntersection = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      console.log("intersect");
      setShowAmount(showAmount+5);
    }
  });
};

useEffect(() => {
  console.log("Updated showAmount:", showAmount);
  retrieveComments();
}, [showAmount]); 

useEffect(() => {
  // Initialize the Intersection Observer only when the modal is open
  if (isModalOpen) {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, {
      root: null,
      rootMargin: '0px',
      threshold: 0.5
    });
  
    if (targetRef.current) {
      observer.observe(targetRef.current);
    }
  
    // Cleanup function
    return () => {
      if (targetRef.current) {
        observer.unobserve(targetRef.current);
      }
    };
  }
}, [isModalOpen, targetRef]);
```

Rendering:

```
{/* Comment body */}
<div className="card" style={{borderRadius: '0px', border: 'None'}}>
  <div className="card-body row" style={{}}>
    <div className="col-md-12">
      <div className="row" style={{paddingLeft: '15px', paddingRight: '10px'}}>
        <div className="col-md-12">
            {commentContents ?
              commentContents.commentModal.length > 0 ? (
                commentContents.commentModal.slice(0, showAmount).map((comments, outerIndex) => {
                return (
                  <div ref={parseInt(outerIndex) === showAmount - 1 ? targetRef : null}>
                    {/* Outer comment section */}
                    <div className="d-flex align-items-center" style={{marginBottom: '12px'}}
                          key={'-' +comments.outerComment[1]+ '-' +comments.outerComment[3]+ '-' +outerIndex}>
                           .....more rendering
```